# importing java time in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, project, java-time

I am trying to use some of the classes from java.time in my Android project.
On my MainActivity class I have the import

```
import java.time.*;
```

***I am using Android-Studio 2.3.3***

After checking my java version via the command window prompt I get: 
*java version 1.8.0_171*

I can't seem to access any of the classes from this java package.
The classes are found here: 
**https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html**

Any idea what could be wrong?

thanks

Comment: no, I am using version 2.3.3 @notyou

Comment: follow the steps in the link and update AS to 3.x if required

Comment: thanks @TimCastelijns